# Components Purposes. Just need a verification

Tags: basic

I just need to know if there is anything I need to add or remove. And also What is the purpose of a switch transistor(Q1)? I need a simplified explanation. Thanks in advance
[image: Diagram]
[image: Answers]

Comment: You can simplify this by eliminating D1, D2 and R2. Just connect the LEDs inverse-parallel with R1 in series. One protects the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the circuit diagram is pretty straight forward. Nothing needs to be added.

Q1 (and Q2) don't add too much to the circuit besides amplify your signal from your switches. The only reasons I can see someone needing this is if:
 1. The relays take significant current.
 2. The switches aren't rated for that kind of current.
 3. The length of wire to the wired remote is long enough that the designer didn't want to waste excess power through the remote leads.
 4. The designer didn't want to scale up the size of the wires to the wired remote to account for the extra current.

Otherwise, if none of these issues concern you, you could really
    replace both Q1 and Q2 with the switches themselves and the circuit
    would operate without a problem.

Lastly, it's a little odd to me that SW2 is a push-button switch. That means you can only reverse if the person's actively pressing it down. That's probably by design though as I don't know the application of this circuit.